# Why do i have compiler errors for trying to pop a splitted `${string} ${string}` type in `typescript`

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a FullName type that is two strings seperated by a space and make my code more pure and typesafe.

```
type FullName =`${string} ${string}`;

const getLastName = (name: FullName):string => {
    const lastName = name.split(' ').pop()
    return lastName;
  };
```

the issue is that nonetheless, pop always returns a `string|undefined`

I'm wondering if there is an elegant manner of managing the `FullName` within the typescript type system and have a type safe purer function.

Comment: Pop returns undefined if the array is empty.. you likely need to account for that

Comment: exactly! I think that here is should be safe to cast lastName `as string` since we're sure that type wise, the string is gonna exist.

Comment: I'm more familiar with PHP than JS/TS... is it possible for `${string}` to be an empty string that still fulfills the `FullName` type?  In other words, would it be possible for the `FullName` type to be met, but with `.pop()` still returning undefined?

Comment: You can definitely write `as string`, but it's beyond the compiler's abilities to verify that it's type safe. `split()` returns `string[]`, and so `pop()` returns `string | undefined`. Literal string inputs don't change that (e.g., `"abc def".split(" ")` is still `string[]` and not `[string, string]`.) This is exactly the sort of situation where a type assertion (what you called a "cast") is useful; you know more about the type of `lastName` than the compiler does.  Does that fully address your question or are you looking for something else?